# parent class constructor is called automatically when child class is instantiated in java

Tags: java

```
abstract class A {
    abstract void method();
}

class B extends A {
    B() {
    }

    void method() {
    }
}

class C extends B {
    C() {
    }
}
```

When I instantiate class C in main, it automatically calls the constructor for B (parent class). Is that normal or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is nothing wrong, there is implicit call to `super` constructor.

You haven't written any constructor for class `C` so default constructor will be provided by compiler which will be.

```
C(){
  super(); 
 }
```

If default constructor is provided, then there is a call to `super()`.
In your case, `C extends B` so constructor of `B` gets called.

If you do not a class with any other class, then also by default it extends `Object` class. So `Object` class constructor will get called.

Comment: +1 for explaining constructor chaining.

Comment: @PaulBellora That's constructor overloading. Chaining happens up the inheritance tree either implicitly (which Prasad has explained) or explicitly using super() (which could be overloaded as well).

Answer (score 2):

> If a constructor body does not begin with an explicit constructor
>   invocation and the constructor being declared is not part of the
>   primordial class Object, then the constructor body **implicitly begins
>   with a superclass constructor invocation "super();"**, an invocation of
>   the constructor of its direct superclass that takes no arguments.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.7

Answer (score 1):

When you instantiate a C there will be constructor calls for C, B, A, and Object. A C has to be able to behave as any direct or indirect superclass, and has the fields for all of them. The job of a class X constructor is to make the object being initialized capable of working as an X.

If there is no declared constructor, the compiler creates a parameterless constructor, so every class does have at least one constructor. If a constructor that is not the Object constructor does not start with a "this" or "super" constructor call, the compiler treats it as starting with "super();", a call to a parameterless constructor for the immediate superclass.

Answer (score 0):

First line of each constructor in java calls `super` constructor, thats how java works.
You should read about it.

Comment: Only if you don't call an overloaded `this()` there.